# Get queue length of redis golang

Tags: go, redis

I am using [go-redis](https://github.com/go-redis/redis) package. I fired below query:

```
rd.LLen("queue_1")
```

Which returning me below result with type `*redis.IntCmd`:

```
llen queue_1: 100001
```

Count is perfect but I want only count with type of `int`. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `LLen` func looks like: `func (c *cmdable) LLen(key string) *IntCmd`

So it returns an `IntCmd` type.  `IntCmd` provides this function: `func (cmd *IntCmd) Val() int64`

So you can do e.g.

```
cmd := rd.LLen("queue_1")
i := cmd.Val() //i will be an int64 type
```

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation for IntCmd](https://godoc.org/github.com/go-redis/redis#IntCmd) shows the following:

```
func (cmd *IntCmd) Result() (int64, error)

func (cmd *IntCmd) Val() int64
```

So it seems you can either get the int64 value and any error to check, or just the int64 value. Is there a reason this is not sufficient?

You can call them as follows:

```
// Get the value and check the error.
if val, err := res.Result(); err != nil {
  panic(err)
} else {
  fmt.Println("Queue length: ", val)
}

// Get the value, but ignore errors (probably a bad idea).
fmt.Println("Queue length: ", res.Val())
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Result](https://godoc.org/github.com/go-redis/redis#IntCmd.Result) or [Val](https://godoc.org/github.com/go-redis/redis#IntCmd.Val) method. As documented, these return the `int64` value returned from the command.